# Can Lucene be used where each entity to be ranked is a set of documents?

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, search-engine

I am working on a project wherein each entity to be ranked is **not a single document** but infact **a group of documents**.

So the ranking not only involves standard search engine scoring parameters but also the **association of documents within an entity/group**. To make it more precise, association of documents within the group also **contributes to the ranking score**.

Calculation of association is something that is quiet specific to the problem and i already have a working code for that.

I am just getting started with **Lucene** and hence i don't know if this functionality can be achieved with Lucene.

**Can it be done using Lucene?**

**Solr?**

If not, please suggest me a way out for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to dig deeper into the Lucene scoring code. Maybe you can calculate you association score and combine it with the regular lucene scoring.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring

Comment: That precisely was the purpose. I just wanted to know if anyone had any experience playing around with the scoring function

Answer (score 0):

You can group is solr.
group=on&group.field=field.

by default it will return a separate list of groups. rather than return the groups as the main result.

You can use your own system for scoring and promote certain fields etc. I'm not sure how you would get the total score for documents inside that group. or if that's needed but solr 4 has group.func

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

hope that's of help if not Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in Lucene. For more information look at Function queries. You can find a good deal of information in [Lucene in Action Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988177) (starting page 185).

Answer (score 0):

In solr, if you use dismax or edismax query parser, you can use payloads. We did this whit good results in solr 3.6. As a starting point I recomand:
[solr payload](http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) and: [solr paylaod 2](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.ro/2010/08/using-payloads-with-dismaxqparser-in.html)
Hope that will help.